# Where is localtime_s()?

Tags: c++

I see localtime() in the  reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/), but visual studio 2012 is giving me a warning when I use it and recommending that I use localtime_s(). This seems to work, but I don't see it in the documentation. Why is that? Is this not part of the standard library? Where should I go for reference?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx  It is a Microsoft specific extension.

Comment: So its not portable then? Should I ignore visual studio?

Comment: It isn't portable and you can disable the warnings fairly easily.